# How to extract data from .txt table with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I want to open Learn_full_data.txt extract some rows from it and write them on a new file called All_Data.txt using a foor loop.

Learn_full_data.txt Table:

```
vp  run trial   img_order   mimg    perc_aha_norm   perc_gen_norm   moon_onset  moon_pulse  moon_pulse_time answer_time answer_pulse    answer_pulse_time   fix_time    fix_pulse   fixpulse_time   flash_onset flash_pulse flash_pulse_time_(flash_onset)  tar_time_(greyscale)    tar_pulse   tarpulse_time   answer  RT_answer   aha RT_aha  condition solved_testphase  RT_solvedtest   oldnew  RT_oldnew   remknow RT_remknow
1   1   1   70  mimg433 0,4375  0,5625  18066   6   20029   20083   7   22029   22099   8   24029   24116   8   24029   24633   10  28029   nicht_erkannt   1055    Aha 1145    exp 0   0   old 2030    know    381
1   1   2   146 mimg665 0,6 0,4 30666   12  32029   32683   13  34029   34699   16  40028   40716   16  40028   41233   18  44028   erkannt 990 keinAha 1240    exp 1   2758    old 634 rem 1063
2   1   1   130 mimg640 0,666667    1   17366   5   19328   19383   6   21328   21399   8   25328   25416   8   25328   25933   10  29328   erkannt 871 keinAha 2121    base    1   2891    old 3105    know    533
2   1   2   83  mimg500 0,454545    0,272727    33966   13  35328   35983   14  37328   37999   15  39328   40016   15  39328   40533   17  43328   nicht_erkannt   1031    Aha 1153    exp 0   0   new 2358    kA  2358
```

The row Vp has two subjects, so I created a list with the subjects from the row Vp (there are many more, but I've just pasted an excerpt from it):

```
list = ['1','2']
```

Now I want to iterate over the list with this code (if the item in the list is the same as Vp, than write on All_Data.txt some rows from Learn_full_data.txt):

```
Learn = open('Learn_full_data.txt','r')

file = open('All_Data.txt','w')

file.write('Vp\tImg\tDescription\tPerc_gen_norm\tPerc_aha_norm\tCond\tGen\tRt_Gen\tRt_Solved\tInsight\tRt_Insight\tOldNew\tRt_OldNew\tRemKnow\tRt_RemKnow\n')

for i in list:
    for splitted in Learn:
        splitted = splitted.split()
        Vp = splitted[0]
        Img = str(splitted[4])
        Perc_gen_norm = splitted[6]
        Perc_aha_norm = splitted[5]
        Cond = splitted[26]
        Gen = splitted[22]
        Rt_Gen = splitted[23]
        Insight = splitted[24]
        Rt_Insight = splitted[25]
        Rt_Solved = splitted[28]
        OldNew = splitted[29]
        Rt_OldNew = splitted[30]
        RemKnow = splitted[31]
        Rt_Remknow = splitted[32]
        if i == str(Vp):
            file.write(str(Vp)+'\t'+str(Img)+'\t'+'Description'+'\t'+str(Perc_gen_norm)+'\t'+str(Perc_aha_norm)+'\t'+str(Cond)+'\t'+str(Gen)+'\t'+str(Rt_Gen)+'\t'+str(Insight)+'\t'+str(Rt_Insight)+'\t'+str(Rt_Solved)+'\t'+str(OldNew)+'\t'+str(Rt_OldNew)+'\t'+str(RemKnow)+'\t'+str(Rt_Remknow)+'\n’)
```

The Code output is just the first iteration from the list. I was expecting it to continue iterating:

```
Vp  Img Description Perc_gen_norm   Perc_aha_norm   Cond    Gen Rt_Gen  Rt_Solved   Insight Rt_Insight  OldNew  Rt_OldNew   RemKnow Rt_RemKnow
1   mimg433 Description 0,5625  0,4375  exp nicht_erkannt   1055    Aha 1145    0   old 2030    know    381
1   mimg665 Description 0,4 0,6 exp erkannt 990 keinAha 1240    2758    old 634 rem 1063
```

The second iteration designated on the list doesn't happen. The second item of the list is '2' and the Vp item is also '2', so the second iteration should return the same for Vp '2' as it did for Vp '1'. Why does the for loop stop in Vp '1'?

Comment: looks like a csv file. Did you try loading it as csv file?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki indeed. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Did you have a look at the Python standard package
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I'llhave a look at it, thanks @MosteM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate through all the lines in your code in the first iteration of your `for i in list` loop. In the second iteration, e.g. `i = 2`, the read cursor is still at the end of the file. You have to set it to the first line in each iteration. This can be done with `Learn.seek(0)`:

```
for i in list:
    Learn.seek(0)
    for splitted in Learn:
        splitted = splitted.split('\t')
        Vp = splitted[0]
        Img = str(splitted[4])
        Perc_gen_norm = splitted[6]
        Perc_aha_norm = splitted[5]
        Cond = splitted[26]
        Gen = splitted[22]
        Rt_Gen = splitted[23]
        Insight = splitted[24]
        Rt_Insight = splitted[25]
        Rt_Solved = splitted[28]
        OldNew = splitted[29]
        Rt_OldNew = splitted[30]
        RemKnow = splitted[31]
        Rt_Remknow = splitted[32]
        if i == str(Vp):
            file.write(str(Vp)+'\t'+str(Img)+'\t'+'Description'+'\t'+str(Perc_gen_norm)+'\t'+str(Perc_aha_norm)+'\t'+str(Cond)+'\t'+str(Gen)+'\t'+str(Rt_Gen)+'\t'+str(Insight)+'\t'+str(Rt_Insight)+'\t'+str(Rt_Solved)+'\t'+str(OldNew)+'\t'+str(Rt_OldNew)+'\t'+str(RemKnow)+'\t'+str(Rt_Remknow))
```

Comment: I've tried to add the .seek() method to the script and the output was as expected. Thanks for it @MosteM.

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to upvote a question until I reach 15 reputation points. I'll remember it and when I reach it I'll just comeback here to upvote your the answer. I've already accepted the answer, though. Cheers! @MosteM